# Pandas: Comparing two Boolean Series and output a third series if both are True

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have two Series, t1 and t2, containing Boolean values.

| t1 | t2 |
| --- | --- |
| True | True |
| True | False |
| False | False |
| False | True |
| True | True |
| True | False |

I want to have a third series t3 where if t1 == True and t2 == True, then it outputs as True.

Expected result:

| t3 |
| --- |
| True |
| False |
| False |
| False |
| True |
| False |

How can I achieve this? Thank you

Comment: Is there a specific issue? Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for test if both columns are `True`s:

```
df['t3'] = df[['t1','t2']].all(axis=1)
```

If need test all columns:

```
df['t3'] = df.all(axis=1)
```